# SvcHost of TermService service on Windows Server 2003 consumes high memory

Tags: windows-server-2003, memory-usage, windows-terminal-services

We patch our servers monthly, and if there are no updates to install, then they still get rebooted. When the server is rebooted, after it boots, the TermService service running in a SvcHost.exe process starts to gradually consume more and more memory, until the server stops responding because of low memory and needs to be forcibly reset.

You can RDP to it initially, but eventually the server stops accepting new connections and you need to connect via the console directly.

Last week we had our 3rd server exhibit this problem and need to find a solution before others start showing the same issue. All are Windows Server 2003, but 2 are virtual and 1 is physical.

I identified the service by running `tasklist /svc/fi "IMAGENAME eq svchost.exe"` at a command-prompt and then checking the PID against the one consuming memory in Task Manager. Services wouldn't let me stop the service, but killing the offending process worked and the servers are fine since. RDP is currently disabled.

I've thus far not found anything similar on Google, and we are attempting to build a new machine to see if we can recreate the situation.

Comment: How do you know it's the TermService that's causing it?

Comment: Sorry, just seen your comment @EliadTech -- I know because I matched the PIDs using the command listed. Once disabled, I never have another issue, but I can re-enable it and the issue presents itself again.

Comment: 1. Does it happen only when users are using the server, or even when he is just on? 2. Do you allow redirecting (like sound, drives, etc.?) 3. Have you tried removing updates that were installed around the time it started? 4. Do you have any special software on you terminal servers? 5. Anything interesting in the event log?